# What is stackoverflow.dluat.com?

Tags: discussion

I recently came across this site http://stackoverflow.dluat.com/ but cannot see why it exists as well as http://stackoverflow.com.

Can someone explain what the difference is between the 2? (I've used stackoverflow extensively, but don't understand the existence of the one with `.dluat` extension and have not found an explanation elsewhere).

Comment: Ah, I think you may be right, going stackoverflow.dluat.com/about and then clicking login takes me to the real stackoverflow site and on the copy site there is only "copyright Stackoverflow - responsive version 2015" - none of the usual links

Comment: Ummm... don't login. If it's doing that it's a combo clone/proxy and you don't want to be providing them with your login details...

Comment: I realised (afterwards) that it was a stupid thing to click and changed my password - worst they can do is add my email to a database now

Comment: `.dluat` is not an *extension*. It is a completely separate site from stackoverflow. At best, it's simply trying to profit off SO by cloning answers. At worst, it'll take your login credentials.

Comment: @Rob I know it's not an extension of the site - I meant an extension of the name