# Can I report scrapers using the (presumably trademarked) "stackoverflow" in their domain name?

Tags: discussion, copycat-sites

While googling, I came across the url

> www.stackoverflow.dluat.com/questions/tagged/delayed-job?page=4&sort=votes&pagesize=15

and I was fooled into clicking on the link.

Regardless of whether it's attributed content from Stack Overflow correctly (I doubt it), are other websites allowed to use the presumably trademarked "stackoverflow" as a subdomain name? If not, who can I report this to?

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå thanks for the link, but this question mentions the use of the name "stackoverflow", which that question doesn't.

Comment: Then it would just be a duplicate of [this question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300631/what-is-stackoverflow-dluat-com) :)